# Making exceptions

Tags: java, if-statement, exception

I don't know why this exception is not working...

```
import java.util.*;

public class a {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x; 
        x=a.nextInt();
        if( x < 5) {
            System.out.print("This is if statement");
        }else if(x<3){
            System.out.print("This is else if statement");
        }else{
           System.out.print("This is else statement");
        }
        a.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) What exception? Not working how?

Comment: You may mean `Condition` not `Exception`, if so, that is because of the wrong precedence of your `if statements`

Comment: I suggest a little more of imagination with your names. You have a class `a` and a Scanner `a`.

Comment: Set of `x` elements where `x<5` contains set of `x` elements where `x<3`. So even if `x<3` it will be handled by first `x<5` condition which prevents it from executing code from other blocks. You need to rethink order of your conditions.

Comment: BTW to clarify your question (since there are no *exceptions* there) use [edit] option placed below your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you meant a `Condition` Not an `Exception`, However, the reason you are not getting the expected result is because of the wrong logic and precedence of your `if-statements`

```
if( x < 5) { // any input less than 5 will execute this if statement and will NOT proceed to the next blocks
     System.out.print("This is if statement");
}else if(x<3){ // this is not reachable because the first if statement will catch all inputs less than 5 INCLUDING those less than 3
     System.out.print("This is else if statement");
}else{
     System.out.print("This is else statement");
}
```

To fix it, simply fix the precedence of the `if-statements` like this:

```
if( x < 3) { // this should come first
     System.out.print("This is if statement");
}else if(x<5){
     System.out.print("This is else if statement");
}else{
     System.out.print("This is else statement");
}
```